Salesforce iOS App. -> Quote -> Add Product Line Item -> Pricebook Selection Asked for More than Once
Recreation Steps:

Open Salesforce iOS mobile app.
Create a dummy Quote.
Add a product line item. (It will prompt Pricebook selection first.)
Try to add a second product line item and fail.

-Current Behavior: The app. asks for Pricebook selection for second time. "Save" button doesn't do any effect.
-Desired Behavior: Products can be selected directly after the first time Pricebook was selected.
What I did so far:
-Look for similar issues online, none found.
-Clear cache, didn't do.
-Update mobile app., didn't do.
-Reinstall mobile app., didn't work.
-Recreate the same in test instance successfully.
-Try the same with Opportunity, and Order objects, it works fine for them.

